# Conversion error in boost 1.49/1.50/1.51 ASIO with MinGW & GCC 4.7.0

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, mingw32, gcc4.7

I'm getting some strange error from within boost::asio when simply including the `asio.hpp` header file, which then includes other headers till `win_static_mutex.ipp`within which it generates an conversion error.

I use MinGW with GCC 4.7 with the -std=gnu++11 compiler flag (see [here](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/5791) why gnu++11 and not c++11). The error occurs in boost 1.49, 1.50 and 1.51 (current).

The full **error** reads as following:

```
In file included from boost1.49/boost/asio/detail/win_static_mutex.hpp:71:0,
                 from boost1.49/boost/asio/detail/static_mutex.hpp:23,
                 from boost1.49/boost/asio/detail/impl/signal_set_service.ipp:24,
                 from boost1.49/boost/asio/detail/signal_set_service.hpp:210,
                 from boost/asio/signal_set_service.hpp:19,
                 from boost/asio/basic_signal_set.hpp:24,
                 from boost/asio.hpp:26,
                 from MyCode\Client.cpp:3:
boost1.49/boost/asio/detail/impl/win_static_mutex.ipp: In member function 'int boost::asio::detail::win_static_mutex::do_init()':
boost1.49/boost/asio/detail/impl/win_static_mutex.ipp:51:63: error: invalid conversion from 'const wchar_t*' to 'size_t {aka unsigned int}' [-fpermissive]
boost1.49/boost/asio/detail/impl/win_static_mutex.ipp:51:63: error: invalid conversion from 'unsigned int' to 'const wchar_t*' [-fpermissive]
boost1.49/boost/asio/detail/impl/win_static_mutex.ipp:53:10: warning: declaration of 'mutex' shadows a global declaration [-Wshadow]
```

As I said in the beginning the only thing I do in **my code** is including the `asio.hpp` header:

```c
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
```

The lines 43-53 from **boost's** `win_static_mutex.ipp` file are (I've marked the line 51):

```c
  using namespace std; // For sprintf.
  wchar_t mutex_name[128];
#if BOOST_WORKAROUND(BOOST_MSVC, >= 1400) && !defined(UNDER_CE)
  swprintf_s(mutex_name, 128,
#else // BOOST_WORKAROUND(BOOST_MSVC, >= 1400) && !defined(UNDER_CE)
  swprintf(mutex_name,
#endif // BOOST_WORKAROUND(BOOST_MSVC, >= 1400) && !defined(UNDER_CE)
      L"asio-58CCDC44-6264-4842-90C2-F3C545CB8AA7-%u-%p",
      static_cast<unsigned int>(::GetCurrentProcessId()), this); // line 51

  HANDLE mutex = ::CreateMutexW(0, TRUE, mutex_name);
```

Is there now some definitions I have to define or any other compiler flags or would one need to change something directly in boost or is it rather something with MinGW that needs to be changed?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be an error in Boost. You can try to update Boost to a later release (1.51 is available) and hope it's fixed there, otherwise you should report it as a bug.

Comment: Hu?
So you're suggesting I should edit the boost source?
Why do you link to Microsoft's documentation, when I'm using GCC?
Apparently MinGW uses a different signature ([see here](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/6612/)).
Also if I look at the error output there doesn't seem to be a problem with the function signature...

Comment: @Lukas What? No, I don't suggest that. I'm saying that your call to `swprintf` is missing the second parameter, which should be the size of the buffer. It's actually quite clear from the error message: The function expects a `size_t` but is provided with `wchar_t*`.

Comment: You're aware that the code snippet above is indeed from _boost_ and not my code? `The lines 43-53 from boost's win_static_mutex.ipp`

Comment: @Lukas Ah, I didn't see that. Then I suggest you update your version of Boost, and hope the bug is fixed.

Comment: Tried that already the error persists with boost 1.50 and afaik also with boost 1.51 (will try that now once again).

Comment: Same error with boost 1.50 and boost 1.51, but I still don't think it's related to the function signature...

Comment: @Lukas In VC++2010 (and VC++2012 and also VC++2005, the documentation is unclear for VC++2003) `swprintf` takes at least three arguments: A buffer, the size of the buffer, and the format string. So if Boost doesn't call `swprintf` with those parameters then a compiler error will happen. So yes, it's definitely a bug in Boost.

Comment: No offense here, but did you read anything I posted above? I'm using MinGW + GCC 4.7.0 not Visual Studio. ;) Also apparently MinGW defines `swprintf` diffrently ([see here](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/6612/)), although it's probably against the standard. If there were a signature miss-match the compiler output would be different and not be a conversion error only.

Comment: @Lukas Well, the ISO C standard _also_ specifies it with at least those three arguments, so besides being a bug in Boost it appears to be a bug in MinGW as well. However, the function as provided by GCC seems to be correct, which makes the bug in Boost apparent.

Comment: I just now understood that you were right and this is indeed a bug in boost (with MinGW). Also the link from above was from 2008 and it seems MinGW now also uses an integer. Could you write an answer, so I could check it. ;)

Answer (score 0):

One ugly 'solution' is to set the compiler flag `-fpermissive`.
At the moment I see only this 'solution' and one needs to wait until boost catches up again with GCC 4.7.0...

Comment: Wouldn't be a solution at all. The problem is in the signature of `swprintf`. Sure, `-fpermissive` allows you to pass `L"asio-58CCDC44-6264-4842-90C2-F3C545CB8AA7-%u-%p"` as the number of characters in `mutex_name`, but that's still not going to work at runtime.